# download a file using selenium

Tags: selenium, rselenium

I have a website that is downloading a file when I press a link.

The source code of the link is:

```
<a onclick="downloadTheCsv(); return false;" id="ddlkkjs" class="buttonlink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$linkebr2','')">Download Comma Separated File</a>
```

I am using RSelenium but when executing

```
remDr$executeScript("downloadTheCsv(); return false;")
```

the file is not downloaded...

However in chrome if I call `downloadTheCsv()` in the console it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link you can give for the download.

Comment: Unfortunately it is behind a password which I am not allowed to share. Given the download is apparently triggered by a Javascript, is my approach to call it in `executeScript` correct? Is there a way to inspect the Javascript function to check further?